# App running, API 200 and Transactions are counting... blank screen

Tags: c#, maui

**What I want the page to do?**
Display an array of transactions, collected via an API. The transactions at first should only display 2 parameters (the ones stated in the .xaml), but when clicked, all the parameters.

**Current status:**
Well everything is working fine. *Sorta.* No exceptions being thrown. No errors. API is returning 200. Transactions Value is Count=5. But nothing appears on the page, just blank! I've reached a dead-end.

**MenuPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BankingApp"
             xmlns:res="clr-namespace:BankingApp.Resources"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="BankingApp.MenuPage"
             Title="MenuPage"
             BackgroundColor="#041014">

    <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Transactions}">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <toolkit:Expander>
                    <toolkit:Expander.Header>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding date_time}" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding amount}" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="End" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </toolkit:Expander.Header>
                    <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsExpanded}">
                        <Label Text="{Binding name_recipient}" FontSize="Medium" />
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="IBAN Payer: " FontSize="Small" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding iban_payer}" FontSize="Small" />
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="IBAN Recipient: " FontSize="Small" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding iban_recipient}" FontSize="Small" />
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="Payment Description: " TextColor="Red" FontSize="Small" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding payment_description}" FontSize="Small" />
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="Reference Number: " FontSize="Small" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding reference_number}" FontSize="Small" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </toolkit:Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**MenuPage.xaml.cs**

```
{
    public partial class MenuPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<TransactionData> _transactions = new ObservableCollection<TransactionData>();

        public ObservableCollection<TransactionData> Transactions
        {
            get { return _transactions; }
            set
            {
                _transactions = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Transactions));
            }
        }

        public MenuPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Title = "Transactions";
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        private async Task GetTransactionsAsync()
        {
            string iban = App.ActiveAccount.iban;
            string url = $"https://example.com/api/mobile_app/get_client_account_transactions.php?iban={iban}";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                TransactionsResponse responseObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TransactionsResponse>(json);
                Transactions = responseObj.data;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error: Unable to get transactions data.");
            }
        }

        public new event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

            if (propertyName == "Transactions")
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Transactions"));
            }
        }
        public class TransactionsResponse
        {
            public ObservableCollection<TransactionData> data { get; set; }

        }
    }
}
```

**TransactionList.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;


namespace BankingApp.Services
{
    public class TransactionData
    {

        [JsonProperty("id_client_transaction")]
        public string id_client_transaction { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id_client")]
        public string id_client { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("iban_payer")]
        public string iban_payer { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("iban_recipient")]
        public string iban_recipient { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("payment_description")]
        public string payment_description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name_recipient")]
        public string name_recipient { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("model")]
        public string model { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("reference_number")]
        public string reference_number { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("date_time")]
        public string date_time { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("amount")]
        public string amount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("currency")]
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Have made changes according to feedback. App doesn't create errors, but the transactions are not showing
**EDIT 2**: More changes

Comment: 1) you're not setting `BindingContext`, 2) you're calling an `async` method from the constructor, 3) you are assigning a new value to `_transactions` but not raising a `PropertyChanged` event

Comment: 3) doesn't matter IF you set the `BindingContext` **after** the data is loaded

Comment: @Jason have tried to apply changes based on the feedback you gave... app runs, everything is ok but transactions don't show up..

Comment: you are using `UserTransactions` and `Transactions` interchangeably in the code.  Only one of them raises `PropertyChanged`.

Comment: What about now? still nothing on the other side....

Comment: Where are you calling GetTransactions?

Comment: Silly me, forgot to add the base.OnAppearing... works now! I should probably get some sleep now... Jason to the rescue, once again :P Thank you!

Comment: Glad you solve the problem, thanks for your sharing. I made an answer as you said in the comment.it will help others who have similar issue.